# Wrong credentials in sending mail using sendgrid

Tags: php, nginx, sendgrid

This is the code for sending email using sendgrid i have correct api key still the browser displays error as

**HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized Server: nginx Date: Thu, 14 Jul 2016 08:14:32 GMT Content-Type: application/json Content-Length: 88 Connection: keep-alive {"errors":[{"message":"Permission denied, wrong credentials","field":null,"help":null}]}**

```
 <?php
    require '/sendgrid-php/vendor/autoload.php';
    if(require("sendgrid-php/vendor/autoload.php"))
        {echo "path found";}

    sendemail('kanwararyan2@gmail.com','SEndgrid','kanwararyan1@gmail.com','HI');
    function sendemail($f,$s,$t,$m){

    $from = new SendGrid\Email(null, $f);
    $subject = $s;
    $to = new SendGrid\Email(null, $t);
    $content = new SendGrid\Content("text/plain", $m);
    $mail = new SendGrid\Mail($from, $subject, $to, $content);

    $apiKey = getenv('Xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
    $sg = new \SendGrid($apiKey);

    $response = $sg->client->mail()->send()->post($mail);
    echo $response->statusCode();
    echo $response->headers();
    echo $response->body();
}
?>
```

Comment: Did you set the environment variable with the api key value?

Comment: No @dlondero is it necessary?

Comment: Yes because otherwise getenv() won't return the value and $apiKey will not contain what you need. See below.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Looks like you didn't set the environment variable with the api key that you're trying to use with:

```
$apiKey = getenv(...);
```

Please check [documentation](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php#setup-environment-variables) here as it looks like you're using the example code.

Just for a test you can use:

```
$apiKey = 'add here your api key';
```

replacing the usage of getenv. It should work. Then you can set the api key in a config file or as env variable (depending on your application) in order to not hardcode it into the script.

Comment: It's not a good idea to set the api key directly in code. There's a good chance it will get committed to a repo and end up public.

Answer (score 8):

I had the exact same issue, removing the getenv() and hard coding the API key in resolved the problem.

Why SendGrid decided it was a good idea to include it in the sample code on their website; without pointing out that you need to do more than just use the sample code I'm not sure.

Just a little "NOTE: You also need to set the environment variables in X location", would have sufficed.

Anyway, all up and running now... thank you!

Comment: Glad that it was a help :-) Good work on getting it up and running...!

Answer (score 8):

### Apparently, the documentation is not as clear as is should be.

**Short Answer:**

I had this same exact issue. Here's the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40519984/2757916) I got, and I was actually able to implement code as displayed in the documentation. Basically you need to use a third party utility that parses `.env` files and makes the data available to your PHP runtime.

From the utility's documentation, I learned environment variables are usually for development purposes only and that production code usually has real data (the secrets) hard coded. The whole `.env` file (in this case `sendgrid.env` and `getenv('YOUR_API_KEY')` is so you don't need to necessarily share crucial data when sharing code such as on Github, hence the addition of the `.env` file to `.gitignore`. Read the original answer for a full back story and how to get `getenv()` working!

Blows my mind why they wouldn't include such crucial data in the readme.md but its pretty messed up and a lot of people have been stuck. Maybe I'll submit a issue when I get time, but no promises.

Check out [dotenv](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv)'s `.readme` for lots of clarity! :D

**Long Answer:**

If you're not sharing code (i.e. this is your personal project or your client doesn't care about sharing secrets), you don't need to set environment variables. Remove the `getenv` lines from your code and hard code your key.

However, if you're collaborating then, *ideally*,  you should figure out a way to not include sensitive information in the code you share. In Sendgrid's example, they use `PHP`'s `getenv` function to retrieve sensitive data but don't really show how to store that data so that it is available in your PHP runtime. Apart from mini hints such as adding the `sendgrid.env` file to `.gitignore` (telling you that the sendgrid.env file won't be uploaded to a git repository), there is much information on how to make the contents of sendgrid.env (which is storing your api_key available to your PHP runtime. Hence, everytime you run your code, PHP wont actually be able to see your key.

However, a deeper search into their git repository and you see a more detailed example where they use a PHP utility **[dotenv](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv)** whose entire purpose is to crawl .env files and allow PHP to parse information from those files.

Therefore, to get `getenv('YOUR_API_KEY')`) to work you'll need to either use the `dotenv` utility or, as I was told by SendGrid's community manager, "*figure out on my own how to store environment variables securely and make them available to the PHP environment*".

Comment: Hey Govind I'm extremely happy with your solution. But still I've a query I'm still not able to use this. I already hard code the api key still says {"message":"Permission denied, wrong credentials","field":null,"help":null}.

Answer (score 3):

For those who are still struggling with this, you can remove then env() function from wrapping your key.

```
$apiKey = ''
```

This will be ok in development, but for production refer to this section on the send grid documentation:

**Setup Environment Variables**

Update the development environment with your SENDGRID_API_KEY, for example:

```
echo "export SENDGRID_API_KEY='YOUR_API_KEY'" > sendgrid.env
echo "sendgrid.env" >> .gitignore
source ./sendgrid.env
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$sendgrid = new \SendGrid(getenv('SENDGRID_API_KEY'));
```

In latest https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php/releases code base using following resolved the issue

```
$sendgrid = new \SendGrid('SENDGRID_API_KEY');
```

i.e remove `getenv()`

Answer (score 0):

For me after you create the API in SendGrid, they display the API TOKEN and let you know that they are only showing it once for security reasons and to save it some place safe. This API TOKEN is quite different from the API KEY in which the sample code suggests you use. This is what I needed to use in the $apiKey variable without the getenv(..).  I hope that helps someone else get to it faster...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using *dotenv* in PHP, the *Sendgrid APIKEY* must be listed in the file *.env* (not *sendgrid.env*, that's a different file).
*Dotenv* parses the content of the environment variables set there using the expression:

```
$_ENV["SENDGRID_API_KEY"]
```

if the *.env* contains such a variable defined as follows:

```
SENDGRID_API_KEY = "SG.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
```

It worked for me, without creating file *sendgrid.env* or running *source* command on it, as the documentation requests.