# Sendgrid: Permission denied, wrong credentials

Tags: php, sendgrid

I am sending email using sendgrid PHP. Here is my code:

```
require("sendgrid-php.php");

$from = new SendGrid\Email("Example User", "test@example.com");
$subject = "Sending with SendGrid is Fun";
$to = new SendGrid\Email("Example User", "to@gmail.com");
$content = new SendGrid\Content("text/plain", "and easy to do anywhere, even with PHP");
$mail = new SendGrid\Mail($from, $subject, $to, $content);

$apiKey = getenv('SG.key......');
$sg = new \SendGrid($apiKey);

$response = $sg->client->mail()->send()->post($mail);
echo $response->statusCode();
echo '<pre>';
print_r($response->headers());
echo '</pre>';
echo $response->body();
```

When I run above code it's showing me following error message:

> 401 Array (
>       [0] => HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
>       [1] => Server: nginx
>       [2] => Date: Mon, 29 May 2017 17:52:44 GMT
>       [3] => Content-Type: application/json
>       [4] => Content-Length: 88
>       [5] => Connection: keep-alive
>       [6] => X-Frame-Options: DENY
>       [7] => Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://sendgrid.api-docs.io
>       [8] => Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST
>       [9] => Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Content-Type, On-behalf-of, x-sg-elas-acl
>       [10] => Access-Control-Max-Age: 600
>       [11] => X-No-CORS-Reason: https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Basics/API/cors.html
>       [12] => 
>       [13] =>  ) {"errors":[{"message":"Permission denied, wrong credentials","field":null,"help":null}]}

I don't understand why I getting permission related error because I have just created the API key.

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Wrong credentials in sending mail using sendgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38368968/wrong-credentials-in-sending-mail-using-sendgrid)

Comment: Please read the PHP manual for what `getenv()` does: http://php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php

Answer (score 2):

That is very common. It will take hardly an hour to understand and do.  You need to set env or use username-password authentication system. Please read the [official document on Github](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php#setup-environment-variables), [documentation here](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Code_Examples/v2_Mail/php.html#-Using-PHP-with-cURL) and [documentation here](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

All you have to do is deleting the `getenv` function like this:

```
$apiKey = 'SG.key......';
$sg = new \SendGrid($apiKey);
```

Another way could be:

```
$sendgrid = new \SendGrid('SG..Tw');
```

Remember that the API key and the from address you set in your code should be related to the email sender stablished for it, not the email that you used when signing up.

Comment: What do you mean by "deleting getenv function" and how is that related to that code?

Comment: I am talking about this line: $apiKey = getenv('SG.key......');    'SG.key......' is not an environment variable but a string. You just need to do this: $apiKey=   'SG.key......' . Deleting means removing in this case. The API token is just a string.  $apiKey = getenv('SG.key......');  // php will look for a environment variable called 'SG.key......'
$sg = new \SendGrid($apiKey); //  $apiKey will be false as it is mentioned at the beggining of getenv docs :  https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.getenv.php